# jQuery remove element if img src of :nth-child empty

Tags: jquery

I need to remove back and next arrows on a slideshow if the slideshow only has one image, the slideshow always adds `<img src />` regardless of their being images there or not it just leaves the src as empty if there is only one image so I was trying to do it like this:

```
if(jQuery(".spslideshow img:nth-child(2)[src='']")){     
jQuery('.next').remove();
jQuery('.back').remove();
}
```

which fails it just removes the back/next irrelevant of wether the 2nd child's src is empty or not.

but when i run this on it's own:

```
jQuery(".spslideshow img:nth-child(2)[src='']")
```

it returns the correct dom node

Why?

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery(".spslideshow img:nth-child(2)[src='']")` is not a bool.  If you want to use it in an IF statement, then use `length`

```
if(jQuery(".spslideshow img:nth-child(2)[src='']").length > 0){   
    jQuery('.next').remove();
    jQuery('.back').remove();
}
```

Comment: thank you that works perfectly,  and it makes sense of course it's not a boolean statement!!! I'm an idiot I should be sleeping not up fiddeling.
Thanks againI w ill be accepting the answer as soon as 11 min go by :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.spslideshow img:nth-child(2)').attr('src') == '') { 
  jQuery('.next').remove();
  jQuery('.back').remove();
}
```

Comment: ok which is more efficient this way or @dom 's way? and why one or the other?

Comment: It's just the other way around for doing the same thing, Dom used length which seem's to be an extra bit of work.